# Keyboard not working in some apps in Catailna 10.15.7 while working in others

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina

The recent Catalina Update 10.15.7 on my Mac Mini 2018 has caused a lot of frustration. First, the now famous accountsd eating my CPU. Now I have a different annoying problem. Often, while typing in an app the keyboard (Apple Magic Keyboard) stops working *in that app only*. If I close the app and restart, it works again. It has so far affected the following apps

- VS Code
- Spotlight search
- Chrome
- Safari
- Finder

When the keyboard stops working e.g. in VS Code, I can still use it in Chrome and all other apps. Its so frustrating since it happens about every 5 minutes while coding. It even happened to Chrome while typing this question.

One interesting observation is that when it happens to an app, I can still move the cursor with arrows, as well as copy text. But I cannot change the text, as in, writing.

Comment: I doubt than anyone here can can help you much - I've not seen an uninstall procedure. The best I can offer is [this post from Mr. Macintosh](https://mrmacintosh.com/catalina-10-15-7-update-accountsd-using-400-if-using-icloud-mail/). I hope you give Apple a piece of your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to create an alternative user account on my mac. I am using that account now, and the problem does not exist there.